# Test Jersey Rest Server that interacts with Hibernate to persist data to a db

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jpa, junit

In my project I am creating a rest api server that interacts with a hibernate dao class and persists the data in a db. I want to test this class but I don't want to corrupt the development database using junit unit tests.

Here is my code:

**RestServer.java**

```
@Path("/restServer")
public class RestServer {

public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BackendServer.class);

@POST
@Path("/createUser")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String createUser(@HeaderParam("authorization") String authString) {
    String decodedAuth = "";
    String[] authParts = authString.split("\\s+");
    String authInfo = authParts[1];
    byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(authInfo);
    decodedAuth = new String(bytes);
    String credentials[] = decodedAuth.split(":");
    String username = credentials[0];
    String password = credentials[1];
    UserDAOImpl user = new UserDAOImpl();
    user.addUser(username, password);
    return decodedAuth;
}
```

***UserDAO.java***

```
 public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
        public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDAOImpl.class);
        private static Session session;

        public UserDAOImpl() {

        }

        private static void beginSession() {
            session = DbUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
        }

        @Override
        public void addUser(String username, String password) {
            beginSession();
            addUser(username, password, session);
            session.close();
        }

        public void addUser(String username, String password, Session session) {
            if (username == null || password == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please check the credentials");
            }
            String encryptedPassword = Utils.encrypt(password);
            User user = new User(username, encryptedPassword);
            try {
                session.save(user);
                session.getTransaction().commit();
            } catch (SQLGrammarException e) {
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
                LOG.error("Cannot save user", e);
            }
        }
```

Can anyone please give ideas of how to test the rest server method without corrupting the database using unit tests?